# Filter the values from list between 3000 and 3500

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to filter the records from list between two numbers (3000 and 3500) and I am facing some issues with filtering and below is my syntax.

```
  val values = 1800
  val test = listOf(1818, 2000, 3200, 3250, 3800, 4500)
  val filterValue = test.filter { values in 3000..3500 }
  println("Test::>$filterValue")
```

The output should be

> Test::> [3200,3250]

Comment: try this :
 test.filter { it in 3000..3500 }

Comment: I can't understand a couple of things with your code: 1) What the point of `let values = 1800`? 2) Did you mean `val filterValue = test.filter { it in 3000..3500 }` over `val filterValue = test.filter { values in 3000..3500 }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html):

`in`

- is used as an infix operator to check that a value belongs to a range, a collection or another entity that defines the 'contains' method

So, the appropriate answer would be:

```
listOfValues.filter { it in 3000..3500 }
```

Notice, that the values are returned **inclusive**.

Answer (score 2):

I think that a solution from [@ivan8m8](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7541231/ivan8m8) should work.

Short example on the list of primitive integer values:

```
val listOfValues = listOf(1000, 1500, 2000, 2500, 3000, 3100, 3250, 3500, 4000, 4500, 5000)

for(value in listOfValues.filter { it in 3000..3500 }) {
    println(value)
}
```

The output from the program is:

```
3000
3100
3250
3500
```

Comment: With our for loop can we achieve it